# A Mathieu-like equation with a quadratic term

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following equation:
$$y''(x)+\left[a-bx^2-c\cos(2x)\right]y(x)=0.$$
This equation is the Schrodinger equation for a quantum pendulum with a quadratic term. If we set $b=0$, the solutions are Mathieu functions.

What are the solutions in the case $b\neq 0$? I'm not sure where to look for this type of equations. Mathematica seems to not know how to solve it.

Comment: this is an anharmonic oscillator, which has no closed form solution; even the small-$c$ case where the potential has a term $x^2$ and a term $x^4$ cannot be solved exactly.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the comment. It does save some time.